# Gimp: Automatically save alternating layers and one set background layer?

Tags: gimp, script

I have one base layer and ten optional, alternating layers (on/off features). So there are 2**10 combinations with 10 optinal layers so I should get 1024 variations generated with my layers.

As a comparison, in Adobe-photoshop, I would use Action script like [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39750/how-to-automatically-save-alternating-layers-and-one-set-background-layer) but not sure whether it exists for Gimp or use **Export layers to Files** feature [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37930/how-to-automatically-save-each-layer-as-its-own-png-jpeg-while-keeping-one-main).

I want to find something like that in Gimp to automate the export of multiple variations from Gimp.

**Is there a way to automate this process of generating different combinations in Gimp?**

Comment: Yes you can write scripts for GIMP.  You use can Python or ScriptFu. For more info see https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-scripting.html

Comment: @BillyKerr so I could initiate system commands and use the Python bindings to Imagemagick for some automations [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ImageMagick)? My goal is to use the solutions found here to generate an NFT collections and probably also other scenarios, any idea whether some addon already exist or useful scripts?

Comment: I'm no expert in coding, however I have used scripts (written by others) in GIMP. If you want more detailed advice, it's beyond my experience. Sorry.

Comment: There are quite a few useful scripts to peruse here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `ofn-export-layers-combinations` script that you will find [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).

The script creates all combinations obtained by cycling layers (or sub-groups) within 1st-level groups, so in your case you would create a group for each of your switchable layers and add a second fully transparent layer to that group.

Answer (score 0):

I found some potential solutions, particularly from this thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485917/gimp-export-every-layer-as-a-separate-png-image), summarising below.

1. Export to ORA file, solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/749561) and then unarchieve it with special software
2. Exports Layer Plugin [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/485929)
3. Export the image as an animated gif and then `$ convert -coalesce ./myfile.gif outfile%05d.png` will extract the frames as PNG images with ImageMagick.

where ORA export has gained most upvotes. This is 7 years old so there may be updated information on this.